# php mysql signup form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm having a nightmare day and trying to amend a html and php to insert information for a sign up form into mysql. Below is the html form and php submit page. I've started with the sql connection to the database and set some variables for add function.

Its monday and I've think I've got myself lost a bit - any help would be fab :-)

```
<?php

$dbcnx = @mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
        if (!$dbcnx) {
                exit('<p>Unable to connect to the ' . 'database server at this time.</p>');
        }
        if (!@mysql_select_db('signp',$dbcnx)) {
                exit('<p>Unable to locate the file ' . 'database at this time.</p>');
        }



if ($action == "add") {
/* ****************************** Do this if we are adding a new record */
        $query = "INSERT INTO connect VALUES ()";

        $result = mysql_query( $query );        
        if(!$result){
                die ("could not query database: <br />".mysql_error());
        }       
        $d_id = $inserted_id = mysql_insert_id();
        $dname = "";
        $demail = "";
        $dpassword = "";
}

// Error reporting:
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);

// This is the URL your users are redirected,
// when registered succesfully:

$redirectURL = 'http://ip/index.html';

$errors = array();

// Checking the input data and adding potential errors to the $errors array:

if(!$_POST['name'] || strlen($_POST['name'])<3 || strlen($_POST['name'])>50)
{
        $errors['name']='Please fill in a valid name!<br />Must be between 3 and 50 characters.';
}

if(!$_POST['email'] || !preg_match("/^[\.A-z0-9_\-\+]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z]{1,4}$/", $_POST['email']))
{
        $errors['email']='Please fill in a valid email!';
}

if(!$_POST['pass'] || strlen($_POST['pass'])<5)
{
        $errors['pass']='Please fill in a valid password!<br />Must be at least 5 characters long.';
}
// Checking whether the request was sent via AJAX
// (we manually send the fromAjax var with the AJAX request):

if($_POST['fromAjax'])
{
        if(count($errors))
        {
                $errString = array();
                foreach($errors as $k=>$v)
                {
                        // The name of the field that caused the error, and the
                        // error text are grouped as key/value pair for the JSON response:
                        $errString[]='"'.$k.'":"'.$v.'"';
                }

                // JSON error response:
                die     ('{"status":0,'.join(',',$errString).'}');
        }

        // JSON success response. Returns the redirect URL:
        echo '{"status":1,"redirectURL":"'.$redirectURL.'"}';

        exit;
}

// If the request was not sent via AJAX (probably JavaScript
// has been disabled in the visitors' browser):

if(count($errors))
{
        echo '<h2>'.join('<br /><br />',$errors).'</h2>';
        exit;
}



// Directly redirecting the visitor:

header("Location: ".$redirectURL);
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>sign up</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />

</head>

<body>
<FORM ACTION="submit.php" METHOD=get>
<div id="carbonForm">
        <h1>Signup</h1>

    <form action="submit.php" method="post" id="signupForm">

    <div class="fieldContainer">

        <div class="formRow">
            <div class="label">
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="formRow">
            <div class="label">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="formRow">
            <div class="label">
                <label for="pass">Password:</label>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" />
            </div>
        </div>



    </div> <!-- Closing fieldContainer -->
    <div class="signupButton">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Signup" />
    </div>

    </form>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whats the actual **problem**?

Comment: You're not actually inserting any values into the table.

Comment: Hi, getting the html and php to insert the values into mysql - its not quite working yet

Comment: PHP has [built in functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) for checking email validity.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `$action` isn't defined.

Secondly, `$query = "INSERT INTO connect VALUES ()";` isn't inserting any of your post data.

Thirdly, you shouldn't use mysql_* functions, they're being discouraged on php.net so that should be a good sign that you shouldn't use them.

Fourthly, and as more of a footnote, don't suppress errors using `@`.